# Select and count statement

Tags: sql-server, count, where-clause

I am new and learning SQL on Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I am trying to do the following for a table of order line items each record is one order item.
any transaction numbers with only one record and a code of #####.
I have tried many ways but haven't been able to figure it out

```
Select * from Table
where count(transactionnumber)<2 and Code='9987'
```

I think I got it. Had to use a different code because QA didn't have an distinct rows with that code. Let me know if you see anything that might cause and issue.

```
Select * from (select Orders.TransactionNumber from Orders
group by Orders.TransactionNumber
having COUNT (Orders.TransactionNumber)=1) as transa

Inner join Orders on transa.TransactionNumber=Orders.TransactionNumber 

where ItemCode=9803
```

Ended up with this code

```
  use XXX
  Select Orders.TransactionNumber,Orders.RepNumber, Orders.CustomerID,Orders.ShipToId,orders.ItemCode,Orders.Quantity,Orders.ReceivedDate,Orders.TransmitStatus from (select TransactionNumber from Orders
 group by TransactionNumber
 having COUNT (TransactionNumber)=1) as transa
 Inner join Orders on Orders.TransactionNumber=transa.TransactionNumber
 where ItemCode=9987 and ReceivedDate > DateADD (day, -1, GetDate() )
 IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
 BEGIN
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  recipients=N'XXXX',
  @body='Merchandisers orders with only Item Code 9803',
  @subject ='only Item Code 9803',
  @profile_name ='',
  @query =  'Select Orders.TransactionNumber,Orders.RepNumber,Orders.CustomerID,Orders.ShipToId,orders.ItemCode,Orders.Quantity,Orders.ReceivedDate,Orders.TransmitStatus from(select TransactionNumber from Orders
 group by TransactionNumber
 having COUNT (TransactionNumber)<2) as transa
 Inner join Orders on Orders.TransactionNumber=transa.TransactionNumber
 where ItemCode=9803 and ReceivedDate > DateADD (day, -1, GetDate() )'
 END'
```

Comment: use `HAVING count(transactionnumber) < 2 `

Comment: This is what I ended up with to only email if the query has results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should include something to group by (Name, TransactionNumber, etc.) do a count and constrain on that.

```
SELECT TransactionCode, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY TransactionCode
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
AND ItemCode = 9987
```

Comment: I'm still not getting the correct results it is giving me every transactionnumber with code 9987 not just transaction numbers with only code 9987. I tried the following but I am still not getting the correct result.  select distinct (transactionnumber) from Orders
where Code='9987' I get a different set of results but still not transaction numbers with only 1 record.

Comment: @Hogwilde1 please revise your comment. I don't know your schema at all, so perhaps provide more information? You're getting every TransactionNumber with Code 9987, not just TransactionNumber with *only* code 9987? This does not make sense to me. Do some TransactionNumbers have more than one code?

Comment: Yes the each transaction number can have multiple line items with different codes and the same transaction number so I thought using distinct would give me transaction numbers that only occur once then the where would define that down to just ones with code 9987

Comment: @Hogwilde1 can you post an example table structure so I can see what it looks like? I can edit my answer to get you closer to what you need.

Comment: The records come from users in the field entering orders on a handheld device. They pick a customer and then add items to the order so each order can have multiple line items with the same transaction number row is as follows (TransactionNumber, RepNumber, CustomerId, ShipToId, ItemCode, Quantity, TimeStart, TimeStop, PONumber, Id, ReceivedDate, TransmitStatus)

Comment: @Hogwilde1 I see. I have edited the query to use ItemCode as the group. So now you're grouping by `ItemCode` where `ItemCode = 9987` and this will bring back unique TransactionNumbers. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I am trying to find (transactionnumbers that only occur once) with itemcode 9987 which is a special code the user is not supposed to send in by itself for a report

Comment: I don't think the above will work because code 9987 can exist on a transaction with multiple rows ( the itemcode is unique to each row) so I need the opposite any transactionnumber that occurs only once (does not have multiple line items) with code 9987

Comment: @Hogwilde1 I've edited it again. The above code should work. It'll group by TransactionNumber, which will give you unique Rows, and will constrain them to only TransactionNumbers that have ItemCode 9987, where the number of rows is less than 2 (no multiples.)

Comment: First thanks for your help it is still giving me results of transactionnumbers that have multiple line items.....this works to get single line item orders but how do I add a where clause to refine it down to just code 9987 after the group by?      SELECT TransactionNumber FROM TABLE
Group by TransactionNumber having COUNT(transactionnumber)=1

Comment: @Hogwilde1 Oh, I see. I added it to the end of the `HAVING`. Does that help?

Comment: I had tried a few variations on that but get this error even when I add code to the select........Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column 'Orders.ItemCode' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the `OVER` keyword, so that you don't need to muck around the `count(*)` and `group by` so much.  That way you can see counts without grouping.

```
Select *, count(*) over (partition by transactioncode) as "TheCounts"
from table
--where itemcode = 9903
```

or

```
Select *, count(*) over (partition by transactioncode, itemcode) as "TheCounts"
from table
--where itemcode = 9903
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with on this that seems to be working correctly for about a week now it executes a sp_send_dbmail only if there are records.

```
 Select Orders.TransactionNumber, Orders.RepNumber, Orders.CustomerID,Orders.ShipToId,orders.ItemCode,Orders.Quantity,Orders.ReceivedDate,Orders.TransmitStatus from (select TransactionNumber from Orders
 group by TransactionNumber
 having COUNT (TransactionNumber)=1) as transa

 Inner join Device_Orders on Orders.TransactionNumber=transa.TransactionNumber

 where ItemCode=9987 and ReceivedDate > DateADD (day, -1, GetDate() )

 IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
```